# Displaying command line help in cmd window vb.net

Tags: vb.net, cmd

I am writing a vb.net application and I want to display my command-line help in the Command Prompt window, like when you open Command Prompt and enter `dir /?`, it will show up the command-line help of `dir`. I would want my application to respond like that in the Command Prompt window, like entering `myapp.exe /?` in the Command Prompt window would display

```
Command-line arguments help:
/a Does stuff
/b Does this
/c Does that
/? Displays this help screen
...
```

below the `myapp.exe /?` command.
Anybody can do this?

**Edit:** When you enter `denenv /?` in Command Prompt, it will show up the command-line arguments list and usage of Visual Studio (and not starting a new Visual Studio process) in the Command Prompt window. I want to do something like that. I tried identifying /? in My.Application.CommandLineArguments but it requires a new process of my application and cannot display the command-line arguments list and usage of my application inside Command Prompt like Visual Studio does.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding command line arguments to VB.Net application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7218217/adding-command-line-arguments-to-vb-net-application)

Answer (score 1):

You can respond to /? parameter from **MyApplication_Startup** and **MyApplication_StartupNextInstance** and create a temporary batch file containing application help and launch the batch file and exit the application.

[image]

```
Private Sub MyApplication_Startup(sender As Object, e As ApplicationServices.StartupEventArgs) Handles Me.Startup

    If e.CommandLine(0) = "/?" Then 'Parameter to show help

        Dim BatFile As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Temp & "\help.bat" 'Batch file path

        Dim Writer As New IO.StreamWriter(BatFile) 'Batch file contents
        Writer.WriteLine("ECHO OFF")
        Writer.WriteLine("CLS")
        Writer.WriteLine("TITLE My Application Help")
        Writer.WriteLine("ECHO My Application Help")
        Writer.WriteLine("echo.")
        Writer.WriteLine("ECHO /a Does stuff")
        Writer.WriteLine("ECHO /b Does this")
        Writer.WriteLine("ECHO /c Does that")
        Writer.WriteLine("echo.")
        Writer.WriteLine("PAUSE")
        Writer.Close()

        Process.Start(BatFile) 'Launch batch file

        e.Cancel = True 'Exit application

    End If

End Sub
```

Batch file creation tips:
http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/write-simple-batch-bat-file/

Comment: Any way to respond inside the Command Prompt process? I dislike popups like that as after closing the window, it cannot be seen again until entering /? again. Anyway,thanks! (Not enough reputation to thumbs up, trying this method...)

Comment: @Happypig375 I have added a new answer, which I think it would solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

Writing to the Command Prompt directly, your exe type must be a console application not a Windows Forms app which is determined by a flag in the PE-header.

Alternatively, you could write to the console using **AttachConsole** Win32 API

[image]

```
    Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

    <DllImport("kernel32.dll")> _
    Private Shared Function AttachConsole(dwProcessId As Integer) As Boolean
    End Function

    Private Const ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS As Integer = -1

    Private Sub MyApplication_Startup(sender As Object, e As ApplicationServices.StartupEventArgs) Handles Me.Startup

        If e.CommandLine(0) = "/?" Then

            AttachConsole(ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS)

            Console.WriteLine("My Application Help")
            Console.WriteLine("/a Does stuff")
            Console.WriteLine("/b Does this")
            Console.WriteLine("/c Does that")

            e.Cancel = True

        End If

    End Sub
```

Comment: *After like half a month or so because stopped developing that program and had started a WinForms instead.* Can you combine `AllocConsole()` and `AttachConsole()` ?